# Property 'errors' does not exist on type 'UseFormReturn' in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

When i use react-hook-form, i am unable to destructure error object from react-hook-form.

```
 const { register, handleSubmit, reset, setValue, getValues, errors, formState } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
    });
```

Answer (score 15):

i found answer in official docs. i.e.

```
 const { register, handleSubmit, reset, setValue, getValues, setError, formState: { errors }, formState } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema)
  });
```